# chartjs error transition of null

Tags: angular, charts, primeng

I am working with chartjs and I am getting following error:

At Chrome:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'transition' of null

At Mozilla:

> ERROR TypeError: me.getDatasetMeta(...).controller is null

I am loading the data over observables and pushing it as key/value pair into datasets like:

```
[{x:1, y:2},{x:1, y:2},{x:1, y:2},{x:1, y:2}]
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Same happening to me. I am creating a graph with no datasets and pushing datasets later (when data has been loaded from a http call).

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you just initialized the graph and overwrite the dataset almost immediately after you have initialized the graph